# Video Player not Working

Tags: android

I have create a method for playing a video in a video player and called that method on a button click, but whenever I was click on the button then the activity page blink for a half second but the player wasn't appear on the screen. Plz help me Is there neccessary to create view or a layout for a video player for playing a video in xml file. I havn't create this.

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController; 
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class OptionsmenuAct extends Activity  {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.video);
    Equity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View V){
            videoPlayer("/Optionsmenu/assets/lic.3gp","lic",true);

        }
    });}





public void videoPlayer(String path, String fileName,boolean autoplay){

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);

        videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

        videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path+"/"+fileName));

        videoHolder.requestFocus();
        videoHolder.start();
        if(autoplay){
           videoHolder.start();
        }

     }
}
```

Plz tell me how's it will worked.
I have store my video file into assets folder.

Comment: where is your videoView ?? You have created it but not added it in your layout . You should add in xml and then get it by findVieewById() or you should add it to your parent layout programatically.

Comment: You can refer this following Link.. I hope so it will usefull for you.. http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/ http://www.androidpeople.com/android-videoview-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VideoView. See example of usage [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html).

Adding VideoView to layout XML file is as any other component, for example ([taken from android site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/videoview.html)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
        android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="240px"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I have add Videoview in my main xml file just after the table layout but there's a problem whenever I'll click on a button then then msgbox appear "sorry, this video cannot be played" with this msg even though i have used a .mp4 and .3gp file format. What is the problem plz help me out.......

Comment: There are certain files that it fails to play, but maybe you gave a wrong path / URL to the video, this can be a little tricky.

Comment: Actually I have add a new folder named raw put and put afile into the folder and the path i'm using for it is ("/OptionsMenuAct/raw/video.mp4",video,true). it will not run i have also tried it by creating new activity but still it did nott work.

Comment: Seems to me like a wrong path. please paste you code in a separate question. (It's hard to detect in comments)